# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString callback

Tags: javascript, ios

i have WebView load html. after scale html

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self setupContentScale];
    self.webView.hidden = NO;
    [self setLoadingIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

scale metods

```
- (void)setupContentScale
{
    CGFloat scaleFactor = self.webView.bounds.size.width / self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.width;
    if (scaleFactor != DEFAULT_WEBVIEW_SCALE_FACTOR) {
        scaleFactor -= 0.2f; // to be sure that page will be scaled to required size
        [self.webView setScalesPageToFit:NO];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = %f;", scaleFactor]];

    }

    [self updateFontSize];
    [self updateLineHeight];
    [self updateContentWidth];


}
```

but i have Show indicator while html scale
or callback metod and

```
self.webView.hidden = NO;
[self setLoadingIndicatorVisible:NO];
```

how get callback?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *StrParameter=@"Test Parameter"

NSString *Str= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var c = '%@',StrParameter];

[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:Str];

NSString *newStringFinal = [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function final(){ return c; } final();"];

 NSLog(@"RESULT STRING: %@",newStringFinal);

//  Here newStringFinal  has Callback value which have current value of Variable 'c' in javascript...
```

Comment: NSString *EncyStr= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var c = Obj.tools.encrypt('%@', Obj.tools.decrypt('%@', '%@'));",[[base64_input_value_Temp componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""],[[base64_user_key_Temp componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""],userPassword];


That will Work .. you can add more as you want

Comment: ok. check = if(newStringFinal){self.webView.hidden = NO;
    [self setLoadingIndicatorVisible:NO];
}?